# Are there any historical fixes to high interest on national debt

Tags: macroeconomics, government-debt

If I were to buy a bond of Argentina, like [AL30](https://iol.invertironline.com/titulo/cotizacion/BCBA/AL30D/BONO-REP.-ARGENTINA-USD-STEP-UP-2030/), it is worth ~30 cents for every dollar, if I understand correctly, this means that, if the country required more money and issues more bonds the value of the debt would be that of 30 cents to the dollar, or less. This means that the interest payed on the debt is very high, making taking debt, even when necessary, very expensive.

Are there any historical examples where this kind of loan interest rates were reduced, so that countries that had to pay high interest reduced their interest?

Let me know if I messed something up about the economics involved.

Comment: Google [Brady Bonds](https://web.archive.org/web/20110928023439/http://www.emta.org/template.aspx?id=35&terms=brady+plan) for example where lenders accept losses on face value or reduced interest rates (I think the later is what you ask?).

Comment: @AKdemy I am not understanding why those interest are better than the interests offered before? Was there an explicit guarantee that lenders would inevitably get the loan payments one way or the other?

Comment: The link mentions the "basic tenets". You cannot guarantee you get payments for sure, that would be magic. Any (even perceived) reduction in risk reduces interest rate payments. Essentially every EURO currency country that had problems with inflation reduced interest payments significantly by joining the EURO area.

Comment: "greater assurance of collectability in the form of principal and interest collateral", what kinds of collateral were used? "some assurance of economic reform" what kinds of reform? "the resulting debt should be more highly tradable" aren't bonds like AL20 tradable enough already?

Comment: I am not sure what you intend to ask anymore? I mentioned Brady Bonds as an example for interest reduction. Now you ask about what the reforms and collateral were for these bonds (I believe). That has nothing to do with your original question in my opinion.

Comment: I want to understand how much of this historical example is applicable to the current situation, and if, in fact, the brady bonds would be a viable solution, or have some preconditions that wouldn't be meetable.

Comment: That is a very difficult question. Argentina already issued Brady Bonds before and is more or less in constant contact with the IMF and restructuring or defaulting since years. I cannot answer what could be a solution for Argentina, and based on the countries history it looks like no one else could either so far.

Comment: Wait, weren't the brady bonds issued by Argentina already payed?